# How to Increment and Decrement in ReactJS using Formik

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, react-hooks, formik

I have a very simple problem incrementing and decrementing the value in my TextField.
I'm using Formik and Material UI in React.
Pls see this codesandbox link

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-table-0i6d9?file=/src/Report.jsx)

```
<TableCell>
   {" "}
   <TextField
   variant="outlined"
   fullWidth
   type="number"
   name={`data.${idx}.returnValue`}
   value={
   values.data[idx] &&
   values.data[idx].returnValue
   }
   onChange={handleChange}
   onBlur={handleBlur}
   inputProps={{
   min: 0,
   style: {
   textAlign: "center"
   }
   }}
   InputProps={{
   startAdornment: (
   <InputAdornment position="start">
      <IconButton>
         <RemoveCircleOutlineIcon />
      </IconButton>
   </InputAdornment>
   ),
   endAdornment: (
   <InputAdornment position="end">
      <IconButton>
         <AddCircleOutlineIcon />
      </IconButton>
   </InputAdornment>
   )
   }}
   />
</TableCell>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `replace` function from arrayHelpers.

```
<IconButton
   onPress={() => {
     replace(idx, { ...record, returnValue: record.returnValue + 1})
   }}
>
</IconButton>
```

You could check the working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-table-forked-fgqn9?file=/src/Report.jsx)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`setValues`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setvalues-fields--field-string-any--shouldvalidate-boolean--void) to update your `values` object. Every time the user clicks the increment/decrement button you call `setValues` to update the current record.

This is what your `RemoveCircleOutlineIcon` onClick function would look like for `returnValue`'s textfield.

```js
...
onClick={() => {
  // decrement current record's returnValue
  const newData = values.data.map((currData) => {
    if (currData.name !== record.name) return currData;
    return { ...currData, returnValue: currData.returnValue - 1 };
  });

  setValues({ ...values, data: newData });
}}
```

...this one for `AddCircleOutlineIcon`, basically the same we're just incrementing the currrent record's `returnValue`.

```js
onClick={() => {
  // increment current record's returnValue
  const newData = values.data.map((currData) => {
    if (currData.name !== record.name) return currData;
    return { ...currData, returnValue: currData.returnValue + 1 };
  });

  setValues({ ...values, data: newData });
}}
```

The `onClick`s for current record's `dispatchValue` textfield would be the same above except you'll update `dispatchValue` instead of `returnValue`. You get the idea.

[image: Edit formik-table (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use States to render the changes, I modified your logic using useState. and added an event to change value each time you change press a button (+ or -).

```
const [products, setProduct] = useState(data);

  const initialValues = {
    customer_id: null,
    reason: "",
    products
  };

// an example of the events
 <InputAdornment position="start">
   <IconButton
     onClick={() => {
              decrement(
                        idx,
                        "returnValue" // the key value
                        );
              }}
     >
       <RemoveCircleOutlineIcon />
       </IconButton>
  </InputAdornment>
```

Check you code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-table-forked-w2tjs?file=/src/Report.jsx) to see it more clearly.